# What is the correct way to wrap multiple sections in bootstrap container?

Tags: html

For example, I have next structure on my site

```html
<div class="root">
  <section class="first"></section>
  <section class="second"></section>
  <section class="third"></section>
  <section class="fourth"></section>
</div>
```

And I have to wrap sections from second to fourth in bootstrap container. What is the correct way to do this? Wrap each section in separate container? Or create something like this :

```html
<div class="root">
  <section class="first"></section>
  <div class="container">
    <section class="second"></section>
    <section class="third"></section>
    <section class="fourth"></section>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct way is to add all sections which you need to wrap as a child element to a `<div class="container">` as you have done in the second snippet.

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="root">
  <section class="first">Hello, I am outside</section>
  <div class="container">
    <section class="second">I am inside the container</section>
    <section class="third">I am inside the container</section>
    <section class="fourth">I am inside the container</section>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think they added `<section>` as an example. They might be using `<row>` as a child element in their use-case. So I mentioned container instead of adding only padding.